# How to write a power function in Lisp(scheme)? What's wrong with my program here?

Tags: algorithm, function, scheme, lisp

```
(define (pow b n) 
    "YOUR-DOC-HERE"
    (cond ((= n 0) 1)
          ((even? n) (pow (pow b (/ n 2)) 2))
          ((odd? n) (* b (pow (pow b (/ (- n 1) 2)) 2)))))


(define (pow b n) 
    "YOUR-DOC-HERE"
    (cond ((= n 0) 1)
          ((even? n) (* (pow b (/ n 2)) (pow b (/ n 2))))
          ((odd? n) (* b (pow b (/ (- n 1) 2)) (pow b (/ (- n 1) 2))))))
```

Here are two versions of my code for a power function with logarithmic efficiency. However, the first function would have a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` error and the second, though works, doesn't seem to function at a required efficiency. I am new to Scheme and I wonder what's wrong with these implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 1st version uses itself to square every value, which creates an infinite loop in the `even?` clause.

Your 2nd version calls `pow` *twice* in each clause which reverses any gain from the logarithmic algorithm.

Your can fix it using `let` like this:

```
(define (pow b n)
  "Recursive power in logarithmic depth."
  (let ((square (lambda (x) (* x x))))
    (cond ((= n 0) 1)
          ((even? n) (square (pow b (/ n 2))))
          ((odd? n) (* b (square (pow b (/ (- n 1) 2))))))))
```

or like this:

```
(define (pow b n)
  "Recursive power in logarithmic depth."
  (cond ((= n 0) 1)
        ((even? n)
         (let ((x (pow b (/ n 2))))
           (* x x)))
        ((odd? n)
         (let ((x (square (pow b (/ (- n 1) 2)))))
           (* b x x)))))
```